# nftables blocking local unix sockets

Tags: unix-socket, centos8, nftables

I can't seem to find any documentation that explains how to configure nftables to allow unix sockets for passthrough. I've got a CentOS 8 box running an LDAP server, and local commands like ldapsearch/ldapwhoami fail unless I disable nftables or manually direct it at the loopback IP address. Any step in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question would better fit in SuperUser exchange ...

IMHO, Unix sockets have nothing to deal with nftables and every netfilter stuff.

Your problem is probably somewhere else:

_ Are you sure that you're connecting to a local Unix Socket ? Default behaviour may be to connect to 127.0.0.1 ..

_ Do you use a FQDN for ldapsearch/ldapwhoami ? If so, then it's probably the resolver that fails.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your response. All the commands work when I explicitly specify to use 127.0.0.1 & they work regardless when I disable nftables, so that's what has led me to believe it's related to Unix sockets. The host is in an automated environment that also auto-fills the /etc/hosts with the rest of the hosts in the environment, which I went ahead and verified all were working anyways. But regardless, this is trying to all work locally within the same machine. I've still not found a solution either way, so I'll check out SuperUser exchange, thank you.

Comment: Check permissions and ownership on the socket file.